# Why does Python's Queue return an approximate size in qsize()?

Tags: python, multithreading

In the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html#queue-objects) of qsize() it says: Return the approximate size of the queue.

Why can't it just return an exact size of this Queue? I understand the Queue may be accessed by multiple threads, but at the moment I call the function I think it's still possible to return the exact size of that moment.

Comment: What moment?  The queue size may have changed during the method return.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It is precisely because there are other threads accessing it.  By the time you try to use the size you get back from qsize(), the queue could have changed.  It would be better if the documentation read something like this:

> Returns the size of the queue.  Note that in a multi-threaded environment, the size can change at any time, making this only an approximation of the actual size.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that 'approximate' isn't the clearest choice of words but as Ned mentions they're trying to point out that simply because the size of the queue at time `t1` was 7 doesn't mean it will still be size 7 when you push or pop values later on.

The issue is that assuming that the size you get back from qsize is going to still be correct when you go to push/pop a value off of that queue can behave unexpectedly in a multi-threaded environment.

For example:

```
q = Queue()
if q.qsize > 0: # size is 1 here
    # another thread runs here and gets an item from your queue
    # this get fails and throws an exception in your thread:
    item = q.get(False)
    # do whatever processing with item you need to do
```

This is an example of LBYL "Looking before you leap" and it's dangerous because of the potential race condition here when multiple threads are accessing the queue.

In this case you should favor EAFP or "easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" and do the following:

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty
import time
q = Queue()
try:
    item = q.get(False)
    # do whatever processing with item you need to do 
except Empty:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: .. or just use a semaphore to guarantee that the queue has an entry.

Comment: Queue is already  synchronized, don't add more on top.  Using `q.get` with an exception is the best thread-safe way to get an item.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I don't understand your comment. That is exactly what was done here, isn't it?

Comment: I think that get method can block also in case that the queue is not empty, but another thread is accessing it (for example to put another item). In this case, it seems that the Empty exception is still thrown although the queue is not empty.